# Not getting values from XML with C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a XML like this.

```
<language code="eng">
  <label lang="tr">İngilizce</label>
  <label lang="en">English</label>
</language>
```

This is example. I have a 402 nodes.

I'm trying to parse this XML file with C# like on the code and I just can get language code values.

Here is the code.

```
var languageCode = doc.Root
                          .Elements("language")
                          .Select(x => new XmlModel
                          {
                              Code = (string) x.Attribute("code"),
                          })
                          .ToList();
```

But I need to get label lang="tr" and label lang="en" inner texts (Ingilizce,English) in same code. I didn't do it.

How can I change my code ? Thanks for your helps. :)

**EDIT :**

```
 var languageCodeAndValue = doc.Root
                  .Elements("language")
                  .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("label").Select(item => new Tuple<string, string>(item.Attribute("lang").Value, item.Value)))
                  .ToList();
```

This code give me a list like this :

```
tr,Turkce
en,Turkish
tr,Ingilizce
en,English
```

But I need

```
tur,tr,Turkce
tur,en,Turkish
eng,tr,Ingilizce
eng,en,English
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I right understood you, just try this:

```
var languageCodeAndValue = doc.Root
                      .Elements("language")
                      .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("label").Select(item => new Tuple<string, string, string>(x.Attribute("code").Value, item.Attribute("lang").Value, item.Value)))
                      .ToList();
```

Your `languageCodeAndValue` would be contain a language code, it attribute and text: `("eng", "tr", "İngilizce"), ("eng", "en", "English")`

And retrive values:

```
foreach (var value in languageCodeAndValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value.Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(value.Item2);
    Console.WriteLine(value.Item3);
}
```

Comment: that's worked for me. How can I add language code in this linq ? Can you help it too please ?

Comment: I need to add <language code="eng"> 's   eng  too in this list.

Comment: @CanYurdugül I'm sorry but I still don't understand what you want to get. Can you show me example for output or edit your question?

Comment: Okay. I will edit the question for you. Wait a second please.

Comment: Edited answer's output is 
Türkçe Turkish , tr, Türkçe
Türkçe Turkish , en, Turkish
Not correct.
I need 
tur,tr,Türkçe
tur,en,Turkish

Comment: @CanYurdugül it's my mistake, you want `(code, lang, value)`. So I edited answer, please check it.

Comment: thanks for your patient and helps ! It's correct now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var languageCode = doc.Root
                          .Elements("language")
                          .Select(x => new XmlModel
                          {
                              Code = (string) x.Attribute("code"),
                              lables = x.Elements().Select(y => new {
                                   tr = y.Where(z => (string)z.Attribute("lang") == "tr").Select(z => (string)),
                                   en = y.Where(z => (string)z.Attribute("lang") == "en").Select(z => (string))
                               }).ToList()
                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: You didn't post your class XmlModel so it is impossible to give perfect answer.

Comment: I posted example nodeof XML and I have a correct answer. It means, it's possible.

Comment: Your xml  on has two properties while your expected results show three properties like : tur,tr,Turkce.   Turkce is not in the xml.

Comment: It's same format with eng,tr,Ingilizce  eng,en,English dummy.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to parse xml is with `XmlSerializer`. Visual Studio can create classes for you based on your xml if you copy it to the clipboard and and choose Past Special > Paste XML as Classes.
Then you can deserialize the xml and you will have a `language` object with an array of `label`s.

```
void Main()
{
    string xml = @"<language code=""eng"">
      <label lang=""tr"">İngilizce</label>
       <label lang=""en"">English</label>
      </language>";

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(language));
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XDocument.Parse(xml).Save(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var lang = (language)ser.Deserialize(ms);

        Console.WriteLine(lang.code);
        foreach (languageLabel lbl in lang.label)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lbl.lang);
            Console.WriteLine(lbl.Value);
        }
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class language
{

    private languageLabel[] labelField;

    private string codeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("label")]
    public languageLabel[] label
    {
        get
        {
            return this.labelField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.labelField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string code
    {
        get
        {
            return this.codeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.codeField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class languageLabel
{

    private string langField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string lang
    {
        get
        {
            return this.langField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.langField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```